# AWS SAM rest api gateway doesn't handle '-' in custom domain properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to map a url like 'https://domain.domain/my-api' to rest api gateway, I use the template like:

```
...
MyAPI:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  OpenApiVersion: 3.0.0
  Properties:
    Domain:
      BasePath:
        - !Ref URLBasePath
      CertificateArn: !Ref URLCertArn
      DomainName: !Ref URLDomainName
      EndpointConfiguration: EDGE
      Route53:
        HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZoneID
...
```

(URLBasePath = 'my-api' URLDomainName = 'domain.domain')

But instead of 'https://domain.domain/my-api' i get 'https://domain.domain/myapi' (the same happens if I use '_' (https://domain.domain/my_api)), but if I map domain manually via console - it works properly.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug (in sam or cloudformation)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what are you pasting in your template, but `https://` and `my-api` are **not part of a domain**. Your `DomainName` should be only `domain.domain`.

To specify `my-api` should use [BasePath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-domainconfiguration.html#sam-api-domainconfiguration-basepath) property.

Comment: https://domain.domain/my-api is the url I want to use for api gateway. In my template I use URLBasePath = 'my-api' and URLDomainName = 'domain.domain'

Comment: @Andrey So did it work? There is no question nor info about any errors in your comment.

Comment: I used these parameters from the beginning. Nothing changed, it's just additional information. (or what do you mean?)